# How to use R to compute Tanimoto/Jacquard Score as distance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I would like to calculate the distance matrix of the rows in an array in R using Tanimoto/Jacquard Score as distance matrix.

Is it possible to be done?  If yes, could you mind to teach me how to do it?

Answer (score 10):

[`vegan`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vegan.pdf) package has a `vegdist` function that can calculate, among other things, the Jaccard index. Assuming that's what you're after. It's use is pretty straightforward.

```
library(vegan)
data(varespec)
vare.dist <- vegdist(varespec, method = "jaccard")
```

Other available methods are

```
method   Dissimilarity index, partial match to "manhattan", "euclidean",
 "canberra", "bray", "kulczynski", "jaccard", "gower", "altGower", "morisita",
 "horn", "mountford", "raup" , "binomial" or "chao"
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you're going to have a lot more luck searching for "Jaccard" rather than "Jacquard".

- Install the 'sos' package (`install.packages("sos")`)
- Search for functions with these strings (`library(sos); findFn("tanimoto jaccard")`).
- Poke through the results for something suitable (it looks to me like [this](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ade4/html/dist.binary.html) is probably your best option; `install.packages("ade4"); library("ade4"); ?dist.binary`)
- If you can't figure out how to use it, edit your question, giving a small reproducible example of what you want to do.