# R vegdist(jaccard): how to include row name for clustering?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R cluster with Tanimoto/Jaccard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755070/r-cluster-with-tanimoto-jaccard)

Input

```
genename  treatment1 treatment2 treatment3
aaa       1          0          0
bbb       0          1          1
ccc       1          1          1
ddd       0          0          0
```

By doing

```
d <- vegdist(mytable, method = "jaccard")
```

from the package `vegan`. Error message as follows appears.

```
Error in rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric.
```

I type str(mytable), I see

```
'data.frame': xxx obs of xxx variables:
$ aaa : int 1 0 0
$ bbb : int 0 1 1
$ ccc : int 1 1 1
$ ddd : int 0 0 0
```

As gene.name are needed to interprete the result, I want to keep the aaa, bbb, ccc and ddd.

I also tried to remove the first column by the following command, however, either of these commands can solve the problem

```
rownames(mytable) <- mytable[,1]
mytable <-mytable[,-1]
```

Could you mind to teach me how to solve this problem?

Comment: @sally : it's best if you mention from which package the function comes you use, that saves people the effort to look for it.

Comment: @sally : with a dataframe as shown in str(mytable), I have no trouble whatsoever running it. You might want to try as.data.frame(mytable) to drop the table specifications, maybe that will help.

Comment: @sally why not follow on the original Q where I showed that this **did** work. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5755070/429846

Comment: Welcome back, Catherine.

Comment: I was using vegan package, but typing "require(vegan)", and then " d <- vegdist(mydata3, method = "jaccard")" and then "fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")".

Comment: Thank you Gavin, however, when I see the plot, by typing "plot(fit). I found the cluster were done on 1 2 3 4, instead of the aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd.  For our application, it could be nice to see the aaa directly in foot of the cluster.  Is it possible to be done by defining the aaa,...ddd are the name of the foot which cannot be used for cluster, so that it will not show the error message above.  It seems to me that R try to cluster using the aaa...ddd, since they are not numberic, an error message above was found.

Comment: @Catherine - I will follow up in the original Q.

Comment: @Catherine - followed up here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5755070/429846

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get with a dfrm I named geneRx:

```
> rownames(geneRx) <-geneRx[,1]
> geneRx <-geneRx[,-1] 
> geneRx
    treatment1 treatment2 treatment3
aaa          1          0          0
bbb          0          1          1
ccc          1          1          1
ddd          0          0          0
> d <- vegdist(geneRx, method = "jaccard")
Warning message:
In vegdist(geneRx, method = "jaccard") :
  you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method jaccard
> d
          aaa       bbb       ccc
bbb 1.0000000                    
ccc 0.6666667 0.3333333          
ddd 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

That is a warning, not an error, and it seems reasonalbly informative. If you don't have a treatment, you cannot compare to the other cases. And the rownames are used as labels. So *what* is the problem?